# Whatsapp-like search icon that covers title when clicked but in the body - Using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

How can I create a search similar to the one used by Whatsapp in its appBar but at the body.

It's a title on the left and the magnifying glass icon on the right. When you click on the icon, a search input opens on top of the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showSearch = false;
  FocusNode _focusNode;

  Widget _searchBar() {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child: _showSearch
          ? Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _showSearch = false;
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: _focusNode,
                    autofocus: true,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Filtro',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'WhatsApp',
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _showSearch = true;
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Search'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey[300],
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      'Tab view here',
                    ),
                  ),
                  _searchBar(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Tile 1'),
                    subtitle: Text('Content'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Tile 2'),
                    subtitle: Text('Content'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Old answer**

Do you mean like this?

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showSearch = false;
  FocusNode _focusNode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: _showSearch
            ? IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _showSearch = false;
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                  });
                },
              )
            : null,
        title: _showSearch
            ? TextField(
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                autofocus: true,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Search...',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              )
            : Text('WhatsApp'),
        actions: _showSearch
            ? []
            : [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _showSearch = true;
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.more_vert,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Content'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes Evan. Just like this. But not in the appBar, in the Body. Do you think it's possible to create such a search process in the body?

Comment: @LeonidasYopan Yes it is possible, the logic will be pretty much the same. I can update the answer with the code later. Even better would be if you have the UI for how it should look

Comment: Sure. I can't show the hole page, but here is that piece: https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/ccc7d16f-ab1d-4184-aaa8-9e853b2a681a/Untitled.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45O3KS52Y5%2F20200918%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200918T115018Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=4a3c9fa156ec4d5660ff36942553dfd4c60ed99d52bccf668ef01c489f34f20c&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%20%3D%22Untitled.png%22

Comment: There is a TabBar on top of it. And a list of card that will be searched i the bottom. Thanks a lot for your help Evan.

Comment: @LeonidasYopan Can you upload the image again? I saw it yesterday but was busy with other things, then the image is now unavailable

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure it was not working anymore. Here it is: https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/ccc7d16f-ab1d-4184-aaa8-9e853b2a681a/Untitled.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45O3KS52Y5%2F20200921%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200921T214332Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=c702409e86ac51597b996dcd0cae2ee7c89d37d4294dec002ef0f727b8e7e3e8&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%20%3D%22Untitled.png%22

Comment: Ok thanks, I saved it to my PC this time. I'll take a look at it tonight

Comment: That is perfect Evan. Thanks so much. I tried to vote your answer but got this: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Do you know if there is anything I can do about it?

Comment: Can just mark it as correct. If not, then it's fine, I don't care much about the reputation pts. Glad I could help

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did solve the problem. I really appreciate.

Comment: Hey Evan, would you have any ideas on how to solve this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052214/button-with-text-icon-that-changes-into-only-icon-when-scrolling-using-flutter ?

Comment: Would be something like the responses you got, with the scroll listener. Not sure about the animated button, can probably be done but I haven't worked with animations before