# Button with text + icon that changes into only icon when scrolling using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget

Flutter Development

I wanted to create a button just like the one on available at Gmail's Android Application.

It's an Extended Floating button with an Icon to the right and a title/text to the right, and when you scroll down the list of emails the button "shrinks" into a traditional Floating Button with only the Icon.

It would be great to have the animation too.

Comment: A first pass attempt would probably be to listen to changes on the list's `ScrollController` and to switch between the two button states when the scroll value enters or leaves a certain range.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a Scrollcontroller which has a property `position`. Simply compare the initial value with another. If they are different, do something with the button.